# Pandas Search Returns Missing Data when data exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

i've a dataframe "energy" which i imported from excel file and did some data cleaning like this :

```
header = 17
footer = 38
energy=(pd.read_excel((path0),skiprows=header,skipfooter=footer)
      .drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'],axis=1)
      .rename(columns={"Unnamed: 2": "Country", "Petajoules": "Energy Supply","Gigajoules":"Energy 
Supply per Capita","%":"% Renewable"})
      .replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea", "United States of America": "United States", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom", "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}))
 energy.loc[energy['Energy Supply'] == "...", 'Energy Supply'] = np.NaN
 energy.loc[energy['Energy Supply per Capita'] == "...", 'Energy Supply per Capita'] = np.NaN
 energy.loc[energy['% Renewable'] == "...", '% Renewable'] = np.NaN
 energy["Energy Supply"] = 1000000 * energy["Energy Supply"]
 energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace('\d+', '')
 energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

after that i tried searching for specific Countries like this :

```
energy[energy['Country']=='United Kingdom']
```

returns the values except when i search for these **3 Countries "Iran , United States , United Kingdom"** but i can see them on the dataframe when i list the dataframe ranges :

```
energy.iloc[80:100]
```

and it is not a spelling error i tried copying and pasting the Country Name Directly .

Comment: Could you post the result from `energy.iloc[80:100]` into your question?

Comment: Alternatively, you can place the excel somewhere.

Comment: Hi @Roy2012 here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cuS3P1DzN2giKg6o4G-l3ikzXBjq-jHc/view) to the .xls file